# Signal 11 (Coredump)

Tags: c

I am getting coredump at "fprintf", help me in fixing this error...

GDB report:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003935467934 in fwrite () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Code:

```
extern FILE *debug;
 int main(int argc, char ** argv)
 {
   if (argc != 2)
   {
       exit(1);
   }
    char filename[128];

    memset(filename,  '\0', 128);
    strcpy(filename, var);
    strcat(filename,"/rout/debug");
    strcat(filename,"_");
    strcat(filename,dateStr);
    strcat(filename,"_");
    strcat(filename,argv[1]);
    strcat(filename,".out");

   debug = fopen(filename, "a");
   if (debug == NULL)
      printf("Cannot open %s for output\n", filename);
   fprintf(debug, "\n\n\t\t********** Started **********\n\n");
   fflush(debug);
 }
```

Comment: You call `fprintf` *unconditionally*, even if `debug` is a null pointer.

Comment: Also, you're *sure* that the filename will never be longer than 127 characters?

Comment: `printf("Cannot open %s for output\n", filename);` should be `fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s for output: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));`.  __Always__ include `strerror(errno)` in the printed error message when I/O fails.  (You may need to add includes of `string.h` and `errno.h`.) This will not fix your immediate problem, but it will tell you _why_ the debug file failed to be opened, which is your _next_ problem.

Comment: You only have a declaration for `debug`.  It is not defined any where. How does this compile/link?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Not to mention `file` instead of `FILE`. And a bunch of unknown variables. It's definitely not a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your `fprintf` will try to print the `debug` variable even if it is a null pointer, resulting in a segfault.

Comment: debug is a FILE pointer

Comment: Yes, but if your file is not found / failed to open, it will be a null pointer, thus raising a segfault.

Comment: Yes, you are right i got it...thank you